# Web API 2 C# how to render a file in a web page

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Um using the following code to render a file in a web page when I send a request to this particular  handle

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("learning/{pdfid}")]

public HttpResponseMessage RenderProjectDocumentById(string pdfid)
{
    var doc = _projectDocumentService.GetProjectDocument(pdfid);
    var contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    res.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(doc.BinaryData));
    res.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    res.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = doc.name + "." + doc.doc;
    res.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
    return res;
}
```

If I type this in a web browser as

> http://localhost:49454/learning/5711130b9aa56d03a0e2f26f

it will download the file in a web page it self

But If I send the same  request from a WPF application  as follows

```
var response = await Client.GetAsync("/learning/" + doc.Id);
```

how may I make it download from an html page ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing content-type from *application/octet-stream* to  *application/pdf*

Browser will download as generic file when *application/octet-stream* is used as MIME type.